# Smarty templating and PHP8 warnings

Tags: php8

Wondering if anyone had any ideas about modifiying the Smarty so that it automatically handles null values being passed in as variables in the templates?

These notices being elevated to Warnings in PHP8 is causing a lot of messages to appear in development environments using legacy code

Cheers
Jonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been ongoing work on this and the team working hard to have it fixed ASAP. If you turn off the debugging on the site it should not display the warnings on the screen though

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: I have asked a similar question about PHP 8 support here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43038/civicrm-support-for-php-8-1. It has information as to how I managed to suppress the warning and deprecated message that CiviCRM was throwing up under PHP 8.1. I hope that is helpful.

Comment: Turning off debugging does not affect Warnings and Notices. At least not for me.

Comment: Do you know what the strategy is for fixing the warnings in CiviCRM - is it a case of null coalescing all variables which might be null or is there something more low level that can or is being worked on?