# Problems after updating to PHP 8.1

Tags: php8

after updating to PHP 8.1, I have a punch of warning, like:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "pledgeBlock" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php on line 138

Warning: Undefined array key "pcpSupporterText" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php on line 222

Warning: Undefined array key "showMainEmail" in /.../uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php on line 230

Warning: Undefined array key "onBehalfOfFields" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%B0/B02/B02188B6%%OnBehalfOf.tpl.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key "showCMS" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%98/98F/98F6DF1D%%CMSUser.tpl.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "products" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%DF/DF4/DF4B6A64%%PremiumBlock.tpl.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "honoreeProfileFields" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php on line 267

Warning: Undefined array key "help_pre" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%70/70E/70E79F81%%Block.tpl.php on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key "prefix" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php on line 13

Warning: Undefined array key "mode" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php on line 32

Warning: Undefined array key "hideFieldset" in /.../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/de_DE/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php on line 32
```

I already tried the tip mentioned in [CiviCRM support for PHP 8.1?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/43038/14050), cleared the templates_c directory, and cleared the cache. The warnings remain.

Any suggestions?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There has been ongoing work to fix the notices.  If you have debbuging on in CiviCRM, turn it off or turn off notice displays on screen for now until there is a fix for all the notices in tpls.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Unfortunately, it is already turned off. (Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling)

Comment: Yes, disabling debugging does not work!